# Utility of the method 'java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue()'?

Tags: java, reflection

Which is the objective of the method [getDefaultValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDefaultValue%28%29) in class java.lang.reflect.Method ?, can someone point me out a situation where this method is useful ?.

The description from the API of Method does not say a lot to me, I do not get what is the "`annotation member represented by this Method instance`" :

> Returns the default value for the annotation member represented by this Method instance. If the member is of a primitive type, an instance of the corresponding wrapper type is returned. Returns null if no default is associated with the member, or if the method instance does not represent a declared member of an annotation type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Annotations have their "attributes" as methods. For instance:

```
public @interface Example {
    public String stringValue() default "string default value";
    public int intValue() default 10;
}
```

The `getDefaultValue()` of a Method from an annotation returns the default value of an annotation "attribute" defined this way. In the example, the default value of the Method `stringValue()` is `"string default value"`.

Comment: I see, so 'Method.getDefaultValue()' makes sense only when the method is declared in an annotation.